# How to remove some character from the list based on pattern in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

This is the field contains list.

```
+--------------------+
|      categoryPathId|
+--------------------+
|[summer|Summer, w...|
|[ab|ba, caa|da]     |
|                  []|
|[shop-all|Shop Al...|
+--------------------+
```

The each and every value of the list contains two values separated with pipe symbol(|).

It will be like this **[ab|ba, caa|da]**. I want to remove the second word (i.e. after pipe symbol) in each and every value of the list.  The expected result like this **[ab,caa]**.

Can you help me to solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spark2.4+

You can use higher order function to perform this operation

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.select(expr('''transform(categoryPathId, x->split(x,'\\\\|')[0])''').alias('categoryPathId1'))
df.show()
+---------------+
|categoryPathId1|
+---------------+
|        [a, c] |
|        [a, c] |
|        [a, c] |
+---------------+
```

Comment: I am getting first character alone from the list. Actually the list value contains more than one character

Comment: I want from [ab|ba, caa|da]. to this [ab,caa]

Comment: Pipe is considered as special character so need to escape that... updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot...! @Shubham Jain